# Windows not starting

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit

When I start system it will ask "lunch startup repair(recommended)" when I click it.  It will take few minutes and appear the message that "windows cannot repair this computer automatically " 
Please give me solution

Comment: In a few months windows 7 will stop receiving even security updates. I would recommend to you (and anyone) to try a linux distribution like debian or whatever. The installation is really easy and in most cases if you don't use your pc to play specific windows games it will over-cover your needs. The usage is really easy too...

Answer (score 0):

If Startup Repair will not properly launch repair, there could be an operating system issue or a hard disk failure issue. If you have a Windows 7 DVD, launch that from the CD Drive and see if you can use the Repair function there. If operating system recovery is resident on the hard disk, then launch a bootable DVD, recover your data to a USB hard drive, then use the Windows 7 DVD to reinstall Windows.